# Find the number of elements in set $A=\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$ such that the element has multiples in each row of a $N \times N$ square matrix.

Tags: alternative-proof, totient-function

For a given $N$, the $N \times N$ grid looks like :

$1$ $\qquad$  $N+1$ $\qquad$ $2N+1$ $\qquad$ $3N+1$ $\qquad$...$\qquad$ $N(N-1)+1$

$2$ $\qquad$ $N+2$ $\qquad$ $2N+2$ $\qquad$ $3N+2$ $\qquad$... $\qquad$ $N(N-1)+2$

$\vdots$

$k$ $\qquad$ $N+k$ $\qquad$ $2N+k$ $\qquad$ $3N+k$ $\qquad$... $\qquad$ $N(N-1)+k$

$\vdots$

$N$ $\qquad$ $N+N$ $\qquad$ $2N+N$ $\qquad$ $3N+N$ $\qquad$... $\qquad$ $N(N-1)+N$

upon observation,I can see that the number of elements in A is the number of elements coprime with $N$.

that is the  $\varphi(N)$
But i am not able to prove this.
if anyone could prove this?

For example $N=3$
we have

$1$ $\quad$ $4$ $\quad$ $7$

$2$ $\quad$ $5$ $\quad$ $8$

$3$ $\quad$ $6$ $\quad$ $9$

and  $\varphi(3)$=$2$

Comment: for n=3, we have A={1,2,3} and in this set, we have 2 elements, 1, which has multiples in each row 1 2 3, and the next element in set A to have multiples in **each row** is 2, it has 4 in first row, 8 in second and 6 in third. we have thus **2** elements in set **A** which have multiples in **each** row of the **N*N** grid.

Answer (score 1):

For a given number $k \in A$, consider the elements in each row $\bmod k$.

If $k$ is coprime to $N$ we will have at least one with every residue in $\Bbb {Z/Z}_k$, so there will be a $0$ and $k$ will have a multiple in the row.

If $k$ is not coprime to $N$ there is a row where the left hand element is not a multiple of $(k,N)$.  All the elements of the row will be equivalent to this $\mod (k,N)$, so will not be a multiple of $k$.

Hence the number of elements of $A$ that have a multiple in each row is $\varphi(N)$

Comment: If k is coprime to N we will have at least one with every residue in Z/Zk, so there will be a 0 and k will have a multiple in the row. could you please elaborate this?

Comment: Let $N=6,k=5$.  If we look at the elements in row $4$ but reduce them $\bmod 5$ you get $4,0,1,2,3,4,5$ and there is a $0$.  If we look at the elements in row $2$ you get $2,3,4,5,0.1.2$.  If we take $k=3$ row $1$ will have $1,4,1,4,1,4$ and there is no zero.  It is standard in cyclic groups that any number coprime to the order of the group generates it.